# Dataverse/Power platform security - selectively remove user access for a record who is part of a owner group that owns the records - Dynamics 365

Tags: security, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dataverse, power-platform

selectively remove user access for a record who is part of a owner group that owns the records.

Our security model is such that the owner group owns records and specific access to users given on exceptional basis through user access teams. We need to support a scenario in which we need to remove a specific user from seeing a record, the user is part of the owner group.

Example:- UserA belongs to TEAMA (Owner team containing 100+ users)

REcord1 owned by TEAMA, due to security restrictions we need to remove access to UserA from the record. This happens often and the user who need access removed is different for each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to **Deny** a user access to specific records. Access privileges can only be **Granted**.

When you need fine tuning on individual record level, an option could be working with record sharing. (Take care, massive use of shares can slow down your system.)

E.g. you could create an extra team and assign it ownership of the security vulnerable records. Then share these records only with the privileged users.